# Reading Settings -> Front Page displays "Static Page" being reset

Tags: rewrite-rules, frontpage

Every day my WordPress blog is going from a static page, back to "your latest posts".

I am not setting this setting, something is doing this automatically!

Any ideas what to check for? Is there any audit log that shows what is making this change?

I am using WordPress 3.9.2 and haven't had issues till recently, no changes to any plugins that i can think of that could cause this.

We are using a custom theme which hasn't been changed for the past year.

The plugins installed are below:

```
BackWPup
Version 3.1.2 | By Inpsyde GmbH

Select Display Widgets 
Version 2.03 | By Strategy11

Select Image Widget 
Version 4.1 | By Modern Tribe, Inc.

Select JJ NextGen JQuery Carousel 
Version 1.1.8 | By JJ Coder

Select NextGEN Gallery by Photocrati 
Version 2.0.66.27 | By Photocrati Media

Select NextGEN Scroll Gallery 
Version 1.8.2 | By Benedikt Morschheuser

Select Redirection 
Version 2.3.6 | By John Godley

Select RSS Multi Importer 
Version 3.13 | By Allen Weiss

Select Wordfence Security 
Version 5.2.4 | By Wordfence
```

Comment: Could you provide a list of Plugins that you use, as well as the Theme itself?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first to update your Wordpress, so that if there's any error in any of the files for it to get sorted out.
Once you update Wordpress, do set the Page to Static page, and check if it fixes your issue..

NOTE: Dont worry about the custom theme.. When you update wordpress, the theme doesnt get affected. But to be on safer sides do take a backup of your theme and DB before you update :)